# How to create a boilerplate npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, gatsby, boilerplate

I have created a repo that contains all of the basic configuration for starting any new Gatsby + Shopify site. I would like to take it in it's current state and create a "starter" or "boilerplate" package similar to `create-react-app` where I can reuse the same setup for other sites in the future..

For example I would like to be able to run a command like `gatsby-shopify-create <repo name>` and have a new repo created with all of the configuration ready. Similar to the way create react app works.

I am looking for any resources on how to do this or any help from someone who has done this before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bin entry in package.json.

```
"bin": {
  "gatsby-shopify-create": "./create.js"
}
```

after you create a node commmandline tool in create.js

Checkout [this guide](https://x-team.com/blog/a-guide-to-creating-a-nodejs-command/).